# ionic 3+ dynamic/auto height for grid

Tags: css, ionic-framework, grid, ionic2, ionic3

I am wanting to do a grid in ionic 3 where the width's are of equal width (50%) and the heights are dynamic like the following: http://prntscr.com/f8ftmc

However, when I try and do this I get the following: http://prntscr.com/f8fvld where all the 2nd column elements seem to have the same height as the 1st column.

This is my code for doing it atm:

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row wrap align-items-stretch>
  <ion-col class="no-padding" col-6 *ngFor="let x of myData; let i = index">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title color="secondary-dark">
            {{x.title}}
          </ion-card-title>
          <p class="italics">
            {{x.description}}
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

How can I get it to do dynamic heights and not always the same height as the first columns - (http://prntscr.com/f8ftmc)